# mDNSResponder not logging

Tags: macos, dns

`man mDNSResponder` suggests that `sudo killall -USR1 mDNSResponder` will enable warning and notice logging, and that `sudo syslog -c mDNSResponder -d` will enable log levels Emergency to Debug. Additionally `sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder` should dump current state to `/var/log/system.log`.

None of these have any effect on macOS Sierra. None of the commands fail, but they don't actually log anything in `/var/log/system.log` either.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion parts of the log system of macOS 10.12.0 are flawed.

The output (dump) of `sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder` is visible in the *Devices > $hostname*  "log" though.

First launch Console and choose your host device in the left pane. Enter a filter like *mDNS* in the search field at the top.

Then enter  `sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder` in Terminal and watch the results fly past in Console.

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped me debug a problem with my mDNS.